# Add attachment in MailMessage using HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have used below code to attach a file

```
    public void SendMailMessage(string email, string subject, string body, string emailUrl, HttpPostedFileBase attachment)
    {

    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

    message.Subject = subject;

    message.To.Add(email);

    message.Body = body;

    message.IsBodyHtml = true;

    if (attachment != null && attachment.FileName != null)
    {
        message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachment.InputStream, attachment.FileName));
    }
    EmailerClass.SendMail(message);
}
```

but no attachment is showing in mail, how do we use HttpPostedFileBase to send attachment?

Comment: Are you checked if `HttpPostedFileBase` is null? Have you already set the form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and using `<input type="file">`? Show related view code as well.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto , the HttpPostedFileBase is not null, also if I save the file to a folder and attaching the the file from that folder, it works.

Comment: Are you sending the mail for multiple recipients and some recipients not received attachment? If that's true, try setting `attachment.InputStream.Position = 0;` before adding attachment.